# Cylcle2 no cycle-pager shows up

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-cycle2

I'm trying to make a slideshow for a website where the pictures slides automaticly (which works), and there should be round buttons to click below it. But the buttons doesn't show up, even thou I have follow the instructions from http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/pager.php

my HTML:

```
<div class ="cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-fx="scrollHorz" data-cycle-timeout="5000" data-cycle-pager=".cycle-pager">

        <img src="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/images/beach1.jpg">
        <img src="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/images/beach2.jpg">
        <img src="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/images/beach9.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="cycle-pager"></div>
```

My CSS:

```
    .cycle-pager { 
    text-align: center; 
    width: 100%; 
    z-index: 500; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 10px;*
    overflow: hidden;
}
.cycle-pager span { 
    font-family: arial; 
    font-size: 50px; 
    width: 16px; 
    height: 16px; 
    display: inline-block; 
    color: #999999; 
    cursor: pointer; 
}
.cycle-pager span.cycle-pager-active { color: #D69746;}
.cycle-pager > * { cursor: pointer;}

.cycle-pager{
    width: 500px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: 517px;
}
```

and my JavaScript:

```
(function(){
    window.onload = function(){ //main
        $.getScript("/js/cycle2.js", null); //Handles the slideshow
        $.getScript("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js", null);

    }
})();
```

Comment: Works fine here : http://jsfiddle.net/WTzH5/ Are you using `demo-slideshow.css` ?

Comment: Yes I have. The weird thing is when I look at the code on the examples, there are span tags in the cycle-pager div, but hey won't show up in mine.

Comment: There's something wrong with your CSS, you have `top: 10px;*`, use the example CSS, and then change the position.

Comment: Alright now I have copy pasted the whole css from the demo and it still doesn't show up :S It got to be something else

Comment: I would comment out your own CSS, and add it back in, bit by bit, until you find where the problem is coming from, that's the only way to debug it really - as if the slider is actually sliding, then it's not a Javascript issue.

Comment: I solved it with another slideshow, but big thanks for your time! :)

Answer (score 1):

This problem causes doctype Use `<!doctype html>`

Answer (score 0):

try this javascript

```
<Script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<Script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.cycle2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){
    window.onload = function(){ //main
        $.getScript("/js/cycle2.js", null); //Handles the slideshow
        $.getScript("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js", null);

    }
})();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/WTzH5/)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="http://malsup.github.io/jquery.cycle2.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/demo-slideshow.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-fx="scrollHorz"  data-cycle-timeout="2000">
    <!-- empty element for pager links -->
    <div class="cycle-pager"></div>

    <img src="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/images/p1.jpg">
    <img src="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/images/p2.jpg">
    <img src="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/images/p3.jpg">
    <img src="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/images/p4.jpg">
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "height:40px;" to the .cycle-pager class.